# spring boot convert datetime with timezone to '0' timezone in server

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I want to store all date time and when a user wants to get information. The server must to return data with datetime and 3rd party devices (like Android , IOS, Web apps) should convert that datetime for specific timezone. The basic goal is store all date timezone with "0" timezone

Comment: do you mean `UTC+0` ?

Comment: yes of course. I did not find another way

Comment: Yes. I want to do so. What way I can do so?

Comment: should I use AttributeConverter or  any configuration changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java8  `ZonedDateTime` to get time in UTC. My assumption is 0 timezone means UTC

```
ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);// This will give current time in UTC
```

To convert `ZontedDateTime` , You can put GMT,US/Central etc in the config file

```
public static ZonedDateTime getDateinTimeZone(String timeZone,String dateInSting )
{
    return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateInSting).now(ZoneId.of(timeZone));
}
```

Comment: i think he also talking about storing so if he use hibernate he also could do something like hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC at configuration it will be stored as local date or given time but when reloaded to representation it will change to UTC time

Comment: ZonedDateTime returns the date in  ISO-8601 Time format which can be covert into any required format.  ZontedDate will give date something like "2018-09-10T11:49:42.189Z[UTC]" this can be converted into any timezone

Comment: I know that but I convert datetime in many places that's why I need more optimal way. For example in usage it should be configured from configuration file (application.properties, @Confguration,...) this way more comfortable to use . Now I am sending datetime with timezone and converting to OffsettedDateTime. after that need convert it to LocalDateTime or Date class. In this case all datetimes saved with 0 timezone when I want to get it with another timezone I just can convert it . that's all.

Comment: not sure if I understood your problem, please check the updated code for conversion. You can configure needed zonid in the config file